# Is the Discriminant of a field extension independent of the basis chosen?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is the Discriminant of a field extension independent of the basis chosen?

why is it true that the discriminant of a number field is independent of the basis choosen?

I proved that the discriminant with respect to one basis is $det(A)^2$ times the discriminant with respect to another basis where $A$ is the change of basis matrix.

I am not sure what goes right in case of number fields.

Comment: Yes, but a change-of-basis matrix over $\mathbb Z$ has to be invertible over $\mathbb Z$, and thus its determinant is invertible **in** $\mathbb Z$. What integers are invertible **in** $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg, That's what I am trying to understand. Why change of basis matrix has determinant invertible over integers? I understand that it is invertible over $\mathbb{Q}$. I cannot understand why it should be over  $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Usually we consider a $\Bbb{Z}$-basis of $O_K$ then $Disc(O_K)=\det(Tr_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(a_ia_j))$ which is independent on the chosen basis. When taking instead a $\Bbb{Q}$ basis of $K$ you get $Disc(K)$ which depends on the basis so to make it independent we regard $Disc(K)$ as an element of $\Bbb{Q^*/Q^{*2}}$. If $K\cong\Bbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ then $Disc(K)=Disc(f)$.

Comment: @reuns, you mentioned $Disc(\mathfrak{O}_k)=det(Tr_{K/ \mathbb{Q}}(a_I a_j))$ and that it is independent, but why does it happen?

Comment: $A_{ij} = Tr(a_ia_j)$ changing of $\Bbb{Z}$ basis replaces $A$ by $BA B^\top$ with $B\in GL_n(\Bbb{Z})$.

Comment: C'mon how is this even a explaination?

Comment: We can't guess what is unclear to you. $Disc(O_K)=\det(Tr_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(a_ia_j))$ is the definition, from which you can prove a few theorems. $\det(BAB^\top) = \det(B)^2 \det(A)=\det(A)$ as $\det(B)=\pm 1$.